# Best Practice for Sharing Styles in a Silverlight Application that uses the Prism Framework

Tags: silverlight, prism-4

A typical Silverlight Application that uses the Prism Framework consists of Modules and a Shell project.  Each module can have it's own App.xaml.  My question is what is the best practice for sharing styles?  Should they be contained in the Shell App.xaml or in a common Assembly?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found was to store all resources aka styles in Styles.xaml and then reference it in your app.xaml as a resource dictionary. Then add a design time reference in each module doing so using blend 4.